# Syntax error when inserting into Access 2013 with Pyodbc

Tags: python, ms-access-2013, pyodbc

I am using Pyodbc and am trying to insert values into a Microsoft 2013 Access Database. However, everytime I run the code I get an error on the execute line:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. (-3502) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this? I have put my code below.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Database2.accdb;")
cur=conn.cursor()
sql="""INSERT INTO Invoices (LINE TYPE,INVOICE NUMBER) VALUES (?,?)"""
cur.execute(sql,("Line","41243"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Columns with spaces in the name need to be surrounded with brackets:

```
sql="""INSERT INTO Invoices ([LINE TYPE],[INVOICE NUMBER]) VALUES (?,?)"""
```

If you have control over the table design, I'd consider removing the spaces from the column names, replacing them with underscores (`LINE_TYPE`) or using pascal case (`LineType`).

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error is in your SQL:

```
INSERT INTO Invoices (LINE TYPE,INVOICE NUMBER) VALUES (?,?)
```

I've yet to encounter a DBMS that allows you to reference columns whose names contain spaces without specially delimiting the column name. In Access SQL, [as in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10920671/2359271), the delimiters used are square brackets; so you would have to write:

```
INSERT INTO Invoices ([LINE TYPE], [INVOICE NUMBER]) VALUES (?,?)
```

The SQL standard uses double quotes, but most vendors aren't particularly bothered about conforming to the standard. See also: [SQL standard to escape column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2901453/2359271)