# Robot Framework database Library - Execute SQL Script Keyword Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, python-2.7, robotframework

I'm doing some exercises using the `Database` Library on `robot framework`. My goal is to update the column `WPA Results` fr the row number 5 from a table called `Parts` as the picture below shows:

[image]

The update will be given by using the keyword `Execute Sql Script` from `Database` Library, please find below the code on `robot framework`

```
*** Settings ***
Library           DatabaseLibrary

*** Test Cases ***

Example
Connect To Database    pymssql    TEST    TestSQL    1q2w3e4r    localhost    1433
${results}    Execute Sql Script    ${EXECDIR}${/}SQL1.sql
Log Many    ${results}
```

The file `SQL1.sql` has:

```
UPDATE Parts
SET WPA RESULTS = '2020/08/05'
WHERE VIN = '547851'
GO;
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

`ProgrammingError: (102, "Incorrect syntax near 'RESULTS'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")`

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920671/how-do-you-deal-with-blank-spaces-in-column-names-in-sql-server

Comment: The error was on the SQL script, it does not requires `GO` in the end

Comment: Are you saying you can use column names with spaces in them without delimiting the names?

Comment: That has worked

Answer (score 0):

Surround WPA Results and VIN with backticks `

```
UPDATE Parts
SET `WPA RESULTS` = '2020/08/05'
WHERE `VIN` = '547851'
GO;
```

Comment: USE     `     AFTER AND BEFOR   WPA RESULTS
USE     `     AFTER AND BEFOR   VIN